# Standard Definition of Vectorization in R

Tags: r

I want to understand better what is meant by some functions in R being "vectorized". This term is disclosed a lot but I have always understood this simply to mean "unbalanced" or "loose" arguments are recycled.

However, as one simple example both `paste()` and `glue::glue()` both say they are vectorized however there ability to recycle "loose" inputs differ.

I understand from the error code why glue::glue() doesn't work but I'm trying to understand are there different flavors of "vectorization" and how would you know which ones are better at handling loose inputs vs. others.

**Reference to glue's vectorization**
[https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/10/glue-1.2.0/#:~:text=glue%20is%20also%20vectorized%20over%20its%20inputs.&text=glue_data()%20works%20like%20glue,a%20data%20frame%20or%20tibble](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/10/glue-1.2.0/#:%7E:text=glue%20is%20also%20vectorized%20over%20its%20inputs.&text=glue_data()%20works%20like%20glue,a%20data%20frame%20or%20tibble)

```r
greetings <- c("hello","howdy")

names <- c("jim","james","johnny")

#this works
paste(greetings,names,"blue")

#this does not work
glue::glue(greetings,names,"blue")
```

Comment: Vectorization always is specific to a parameter. A function can be vectorized for one of its parameters but not vectorized for other parameters. "Proper vectorization" means that a vector is accepted as input and any loops over that vector are done by compiled code, i.e. usually in C or C++.

Comment: Thank you! this very clear to me now. Is this a standard compuster science concept that applies in any context (R, Python, etc?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectorization means that the code can handle vectors with multiple elements without any special `map` or `lapply` function, and it is often performed quickly using parallel processing and multithreading. It doesn't necessarily have anything to do with recycling uneven inputs. A slight modification of your sample data makes this clearer:

```r
greetings <- c("hello","howdy")

firstnames <- c("jim","james")

colors <- c("blue", "red")

#this works - vectorized
paste(greetings,firstnames,colors)
[1] "hello jim blue"  "howdy james red"

#this errors - not vectorized
glue::glue(greetings,firstnames,colors)
Error: All unnamed arguments must be length 1

#this works - doesn't need to be vectorized
glue::glue(greetings[1], firstnames[1], colors[1])
hellojimblue
```

As you can see, paste can handle vectors with multiple elements simultaneously, whereas glue can only handle vectors with one element at a time.

However, if we use `mapply` with glue, we can apply the function to vectors but in a slower, more artificial way:

```r
#Artificial vectorization - slower
mapply(function(x,y,z) {glue::glue(x,y,z)}, greetings, firstnames, colors, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
[1] "hellojimblue"  "howdyjamesred"
```

I would not say that `glue::glue` is vectorized at all in the way you are attempting to use it, even though it can handle many arguments. It should be able to handle many vectors of arguments as above to call itself fully vectorized.

Comment: this is where I got the glue vectorization: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/10/glue-1.2.0/#:~:text=glue%20is%20also%20vectorized%20over%20its%20inputs.&text=glue_data()%20works%20like%20glue,a%20data%20frame%20or%20tibble).

Comment: This context of vectorization is a slightly different use case than pasting vectors together, it involves filling vectors of words into the brackets. In that context, glue is vectorized. Just not for pasting.

Comment: thanks @dcsuka - I guess I should understand the ability of a function to "recycle" a "loose" input is a byproduct of vectorization - not the definition of vectorization itself?

Comment: Yes, and recycling is not always necessary to implement for vectorization. For example, the following two commands reflect different strategies, glue errs entirely:

Comment: glue::glue("{month.abb} word {month.name[1:5]}");

paste(month.abb, month.name[1:5])